# swift how to compare generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a protocol called `SomeProtocol`

I want to create a function that get an object that confirms to this protocol, and add it to an array.

then I have another function that remove an object from this array.

```
var allObjs = [SomeProtocol]()

func addObj<T: AnyObject where T: SomeProtocol>(obj: T) {
    allObjs.append(obj)
}

func removeObj<T: AnyObject where T: SomeProtocol>(obj: T) {
    for someObj in allObjs {
        if someObj == obj { // compile time error -> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SomeProtocol' and 'T'

        }
    }
}
```

This code will cause a compile time error "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SomeProtocol' and 'T'"

not sure how can i fix that, both object where defined as AnyObject who confirm to the SomeProtocol protocol, so what is the problem here?

Comment: The questions to ask yourself: what are you expecting `==` to do?  Where would this ability to use `==` on two arbitrary `SomeProtocol` types come from?  Have you defined a `==` operator that takes two `SomeProtocol`?  Do you want _reference_ equality (`===` rather than `==`)?

Comment: yes i want a reference equality just to check if this is the same object, but === doesn't work as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two custom objects in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942511/comparing-two-custom-objects-in-swift), and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29943227/1187415) should solve your problem.

Comment: See also [Find index of object in an array of type SomeProtocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344222/find-index-of-object-in-an-array-of-type-someprotocol).

Answer (score 4):

For comparing two generics, you can declare the generics such that, types, that are capable to be in the place of your generic type, should conform to [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) protocol.

```
struct Heap<T: Comparable>{
var heap = [T]()
}}
```

Now we will be able to do:-

```
if heap[parentIndex] < heap[childIndex] {
//Your code
}
```

How this works?

As we know, conforming to a protocol means implementing all the required methods in that protocol. **Comparable** protocol has got all the comparison methods as required parameters, and any type that is implementing **Comparable** will be able to do a comparison.

Happy coding using Generics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reference equality, then you need to ensure `SomeProtocol` only applies to classes (since you can’t use reference equality on structs, as they’re value types):

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class { }
```

Now, only classes can implement `SomeProtocol`.

You don’t need generics to use reference equality now, just regular run-time polymorphism:

```
func removeObj(obj: SomeProtocol) {
    // since any SomeProtocol-conforming object
    // must be a class, you can now use ===
    if let idx = allObjs.indexOf({ $0 === obj}) {
        allObjs.removeAtIndex(idx)
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason i can't call indexOf on my array

Comment: That’s a 2.0 feature, if you’re using 1.2 you still need to do it with a loop as in your original question.

Comment: can u pls give an example how to loop and remove object from the array? in objective c i used to store those objectsToRemove in an array and then call removeObjectsInArray:

Comment: That’s a separate question, accept this one (assuming it answers your question) and post a new one (though probably there is already one asking this)

Answer (score 0):

The generic function must also conform to the `Equatable` protocol

Comment: Not quite as simple as that in this case – the array is of protocols rather than actual objects, so would need to equate two potentially different types both adhering to the same protocol.

Comment: should i define an array of AnyObject that confirm to the protocol? can i even do that?

Comment: No, you can’t do that, since `Equatable` has an associated type – it can only be used as a constraint, you can’t have an array of different `Equatable` types.